# query takes 70 ms to execute

Tags: php, mysql

I have an MySQL table named `i_visited` structured like: `userid,tid,dateline`

And I run this condition in view_thread.php page:

```
if (db('count','SELECT userid FROM i_visited 
                WHERE tid = '.intval($_GET['id']).' 
                  AND userid = '.$user['id']))

  mysql_query('UPDATE i_visited 
               SET dateline = unix_timestamp(now()) 
               WHERE userid = '.$user['id'].' 
                 AND tid = '.intval($_GET['id']));
else 
  mysql_query('INSERT INTO i_visited (userid,tid,dateline) VALUES 
              ('.$user['id'].','.intval($_GET['id']).',unix_timestamp(now()))');
```

The problem is that it executes in 80/100 ms (on Windows) 40/60 (on Linux)

> 1 row affected. (query executed in 0.0707 sec)

The `mysql_num_rows()` aka `db('count',sql)` uses 2 / 3 ms, so the problem is at the update and the insert.

P.S. `i_visited` is an utf8_unicode_ci (InnoDB), has anyone seen this problem?
Other queries run normal (2 / 3 milliseconds)

```
CREATE TABLE i_visited ( 
  userid int(10) NOT NULL, 
  tid int(10) unsigned NOT NULL, 
  dateline int(10) NOT NULL, 
  KEY userid (userid,tid), 
  KEY userid_2 (userid), 
  KEY tid (tid) ) 
ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci
```

Comment: Have you already tried an `REPLACE INTO`

Comment: Are you sure that like, your indexes are set and ok? Like?

Comment: Include the output of SHOW CREATE TABLE i_visited, and also tell use how many rows are in that table.

Comment: @Innogood I like totally like what you did there

Comment: `CREATE TABLE i_visited ( userid int(10) NOT NULL, tid int(10) unsigned NOT NULL, dateline int(10) NOT NULL, KEY userid (userid,tid), KEY userid_2 (userid), KEY tid (tid) ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci`

Comment: @edduvs feel free to edit your questions and add information to them. I added that create table to your post.

Comment: I will try that REPLACE INTO, see how it works.

Comment: Also check your general MySQL (and InnoDB in particular) settings. Default MySQL settings are not the best, regarding InnoDB. You can start here: http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2007/11/01/innodb-performance-optimization-basics/

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to do a select to check existence and then choose either Update or Insert.

You can use MySQL's [`ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert-on-duplicate.html) Feature like this.

```
$query = 'INSERT INTO 
            i_visited (userid,tid,dateline) 
            VALUES (' . 
                $user['id'] . ',' . 
                intval($_GET['id']) . ',
                unix_timestamp(now())) 
            ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE 
                dateline = unix_timestamp(now())';
mysql_query($query);
```

This query will insert a new row if there is now `KEY` conflict, and in case a duplicate key is being inserted, it will instead execute the update part.

And as you have a `KEY userid (userid,tid)` in your CREATE Statement the above query is equivalent to your `if...else` block.

Try this and see if there are any gains

You can also use `REPLACE INTO`, as there are only the specified 3 columns, like this

```
$query = 'REPLACE INTO 
            i_visited (userid,tid,dateline) 
            VALUES (' . 
                $user['id'] . ',' . 
                intval($_GET['id']) . ',
                unix_timestamp(now()))';
mysql_query($query);
```

But I would suggest looking at `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` as it is more flexible, as it can be used on a table with any number of columns, whereas `REPLACE INTO` would only work in some limited cases as other column values would also need to be filled in the `REPLACE INTO` statement unnecessarily

Comment: Same stupid thing, ~100 ms to process that query. Even using on duplicate key and that new table definition.

Comment: @edduvs try simply executing `mysql_query('UPDATE i_visited SET dateline = unix_timestamp(now()) WHERE userid = '.$user['id'].' AND tid = '.intval($_GET['id']));` for a  known pre existing `id` and `tid`, see how long it takes. Might help in narrowing the cause. Even if you do it via AJAX, a large number of simultaneous users would slow down the server if an SQL query takes so long to execute. Something is definately wrong here. I myself try to optimize any query over 20ms in my application.

Answer (score 0):

I think (part) of the problem is that your table does not have an explicit primary key.
You've only declared secondary keys.

Change the definition to:

```
CREATE TABLE i_visited ( 
  userid int(10) NOT NULL, 
  tid int(10) unsigned NOT NULL, 
  dateline int(10) NOT NULL, 
  PRIMARY KEY userid (userid,tid), <<----------
  KEY userid_2 (userid), 
  KEY tid (tid) ) 
ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci
```

InnoDB does not work well without an **explicit** primary key defined.

Comment: Can you help me declaring the table's structure , i know i have to modify the keys for this to work ok, i was just reading about on duplicate key, thanks for the future support.

Comment: @edduvs, use an `alter table` statement, see here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/alter-table.html  Of course its much easier in a editor like phpAdmin or MySQL workbench.